# JavaScript function not working with gradients

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

Sorry for the vague question title,

```
var background = [
  "background: linear-gradient(to left, #F0C27B, #4B1248)",
  "background: linear-gradient(to left, #5614B0, #DBD65C)",
  "background: linear-gradient(to left, #004FF9, #FFF94C)",
  "background: linear-gradient(to left, #FFA17F, #00223E)",
  "/css/1.png",
  "/css/2.png",
  "/css/3.png",
  "/css/4.png"
];

setInterval(function() {
  var chosenImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * (8));
  if chosenImage < 4 {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "url(" + background[chosenImage] + ")";
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + background[chosenImage] + ")";
  }
}, 10000);
```

Basically this (with the css and html files) shuffles the background images on the site to display a random one every ten seconds. Before when I had the code without the gradients

```
var images = ["1.png", "2.png", ...] (up to 4)
```

and the setInterval like this

```
setInterval(function() {
  var chosenImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4));
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + background[chosenImage] + ")";
}, 10000);
```

it worked fine, but once I implemented what you see in the snippet at the beginning, the image stopped changing and instead displayed the default image I had specified in the css file.

Any ideas as to why it's not changing with gradients? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things wrong with how you have the gradients setup.

First, you don't want to include `background:` in the style, as you are already directly assigning to the `backgroundImage` and `backgroundColor` properties.

Second, you don't want to wrap the gradient version with `url( )`. `url( )` literally expects a URL, but you're giving it a gradient.

Lastly, you don't want to use `backgroundColor`, as gradients are treated as images, so you can simplify your script to something like this.

```
var background = [
    "linear-gradient(to left, #F0C27B, #4B1248)",
    "linear-gradient(to left, #5614B0, #DBD65C)",
    "linear-gradient(to left, #004FF9, #FFF94C)",
    "linear-gradient(to left, #FFA17F, #00223E)",
    "url(/css/1.png)",
    "url(/css/2.png)",
    "url(/css/3.png)",
    "url(/css/4.png)"
];

setInterval( function() {
    var chosenImage = Math.floor( Math.random( ) * 8 );

    document.body.style.background = background[ chosenImage ];
}, 10000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your `setInterval()` function:

- You're missing brackets around the test condition
- For the first four elements of the `background` array, you're setting the background image to `"url("+[element]+")"`, but those elements are not images. Instead, set the `style` directly to that.

The following should do the trick:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var chosenImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * (8));
    if (chosenImage < 4) {
        document.body.style = background[chosenImage];
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + background[chosenImage] + ")";
    }
}, 10000);
```

This should do the trick.